# Pass updated data to root component

Tags: reactjs

here is my code :

```
var data = "hello";

var RootComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <p className="root">
                {this.props.data}
            </p>
        );
    }
});

React.renderComponent(
    <RootComponent data="data" />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

I want to change the value of data(initially hello), so the page is refreshed with the new data value. But the function that change data is not in React, and I can't find a way to "plug" them. Any idea how to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: You can call `React.renderComponent(...)` again after the data was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen on the change and call React.renderComponent() as mentioned by Felix. Per React's documentation:

> Render a React component into the DOM in the supplied container and return a reference to the component.
>
> If the React component was previously rendered into container, this
>   will perform an update on it and only mutate the DOM as necessary to
>   reflect the latest React component.
>
> If the optional callback is provided, it will be executed after the
>   component is rendered or updated.

If you have the ability to look into using Flux Stores for your model layer I would strongly encourage you to do so.